# Flagged at the same time question was closed

Tags: support, flags, closed-questions

I went to flag a post as not constructive. Just as I submitted the flag the page refreshed and the question was already closed as <s>not constructive</s> not a real question (my bad). Normally you cannot flag for "it doesn't belong here..." after the question is closed.

What happens with my flag in this situation?

[image]

Comment: It should be automatically resolved.  I don't know if it will be marked as helpful or disputed though.

Comment: @Servy Ok, that's what I thought/hoped. If the user ends up deleting the post (or mods delete it?), it should then auto resolve to helpful right?

Comment: I believe most of those situations resolve to "disputed".

Comment: @Servy Awww... ok, Thanks for your help. I had never had something like that happen and was wondering what the outcome would be since it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Assuming [this is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737428/how-much-time-it-takes-to-learn-java-completly), there's actually two unresolved  "not constructive" flags in the 10k flags view. Since it has 2 delete votes, your flag might actually get a "helpful" resolution if the post is deleted before a moderator handles it.

Comment: @Mat Thanks, that is the question.

Comment: @Mat - What's the 10k flags view?

Comment: Users with 10k+ reputation get access to some "moderator tools", including a view on some of the flags (not the custom ones, but things like close flags, not-an-answer, ect). See the 10k privilege page: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools, @JoshDM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to what Mat had said:

> Assuming this is the question, there's actually two unresolved "not constructive" flags in the 10k flags view. Since it has 2 delete votes, your flag might actually get a "helpful" resolution if the post is deleted before a moderator handles it. – Mat

It turned out that the flag was deemed helpful.

I had initially thought that in this situation the flag just disappeared since the question was already closed before my flag came in but that is not the case.